# calling a variable in option javascript

Tags: javascript, google-datalayer

What I would like to achieve is when student pick their number the it will push their name to the tracking. Like this:

```
window.dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'event',
  'name': 'Joe'
});
```

I tried to achieve it with this but failed.

```
window.dataLayer.push({
  var studentName = '~@studentNumber~';
  if (studentName=="01") {
    return "Joe";
  }
  else if (studentName=="02") {
    return "Jane";
  }
  else {
    return "error - User has no name"
  };
  'event': 'event',
  'name': name
});
```

What did I do wrong and how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: You cannot have if statements in an object literal

Comment: Jro is right, make a function to handle that, return the object, and push it in the array insted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have if statements in an object literal. However, you can use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Try this:

```js
var studentName = '~@studentNumber~';
window.dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'event',
  'name': studentName=="01" ? "Joe" : studentName=="02" ? "Jane" : "error - User has no name"
});
```

Also I'm not sure how `'~@studentNumber~'` would work. I assume some library or something will replace it with your desired value.

Comment: Thank you so much. It does work. `~@studentNumber~` is a very specific value from a library.

Answer (score 0):

> In javascript when you write { obj:value} this is object pattern you can't write if statement here so simple for you

```
var studentName = '~@studentNumber~';
var name = "error - User has no name";
if (studentName=="01") {
  name = "Joe";
}
else if (studentName=="02") {
 name = "Jane";
}

window.dataLayer.push({
'event': 'event',
'name': name
});
```

you can also follow above answer